# Как получить значение из HashMap через stream и фильтрацию?

Tags: java, коллекции, java-stream

Имеется мапа с User в качестве values, и у юзера есть поле email.

```
private Map<Integer, User> userMap = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();
```

Имеется метод для получения User с конкретным email из мапы

```
public User getByEmail(String email) {
        log.info("getByEmail {}", email);
        for (Map.Entry<Integer, User> entry : userMap.entrySet()) {
            User user = entry.getValue();
            if (user.getEmail().equals(email)) {
                return user;
            }
        }
        return null;
}
```

Задача - переписать метод через Stream API.
Моя текущая неверная попытка выглядит так:

```
return userMap.entrySet().stream().filter(user -> user.getValue().getEmail().equals(email));
```

Подскажите - что еще добавить(или исправить вообще) для получения требуемого?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

У вас в стриме нет терминальной операции - той которая возвращает результат. То есть, из исходного стрима, вы, получаете отфильтрованный стрим, а дальше ничего не происходит.
Вернуть первого юзера, у которого совпал email можно так:

```
 return userMap.entrySet()
                .stream()
                .map(Map.Entry::getValue)
                .filter(user -> user.getEmail().equals(email))
                .findFirst()
                .orElse(null);
```

Немного изящней:

```
        return userMap.values()
            .stream()
            .filter(user -> user.getEmail().equals(email))
            .findFirst()
            .orElse(null);
```

Comment: сработало! большое спасибо)